# colocar uma informação no final do reporte em Crystal Reporting

Tags: crystal-reports

Quero colocar uma informação no final, numa pagina a parte do reporte, em Crystal Reports.
Tentei colocar um novo group footer mas aparece o cabeçalho. Ao colocar a condição
  pagenumber<>1   no suppress, o cabeçalho aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Colocar:
   Page hader b suppress:pagenumber<>1,
   Page header i suppress:pagenumber=1 or pagenumber=totalcountpage,
   Group Footer #1d - New PageAfter,
   Page Footer suppress:totalpagecount-1=pagenumber or totalpagecount=pagenumber